# What are these hybrids from National Semiconductor?

Tags: identification, components, vintage

[image]I found some parts in my junk drawer that I can't identify. I'm pretty sure they're National Semiconductor hybrid circuits from 1969-1970, but I have no access to a National Hybrid Products databook. The part numbers are:

- NS NH0009C
- NS NH00012C

Both are in 12-lead TO-8 cans. Does anybody know what these are, or better yet, can point me to a datasheet?

Thanks

Comment: Are you contemplating using them for an unknown project (that you cannot yet define) because you have no idea what the parts are or, whether they are reliable enough for anything (based on their unknown 40+ year history in a junk-draw)?

Comment: I remember those part numbers as “Damn Fast Buffers”  maybe?

Comment: LH0033 is buffer;LH0063 is damn-fast buffer.

Comment: Picture?  There might be another clue.

Comment: I added a picture of the devices. They're big packages... diameter is a little over 1/2".Having no data, I have no plans for them, and am just curious what they are. Although that could change if they end up being something interesting.

Comment: There are a number of databooks on the Internet archive you can try also try there

Comment: I've found a few National databooks on the internet, but the only hits I've gotten on the Hybrid Products Databook have been books for sale, and my degree of curiosity doesn't warrant buying one. Nothing on bitsavers either. I've only seen a couple of references to the NH00012C that suggest it might be some kind of 1 amp MOS driver, but I've gotten no hits at all on the NH0009C.

Comment: Fascinating package, don't see those often.

Answer (score 1):

The NH prefix doesn't mean they are hybrids.  There's an article in March 1970 Electronics World magazine (https://www.americanradiohistory.com/Archive-Electronics-World/70s/1970/Electronics-World-1970-03.pdf) that lists the NH0009 as being a clock driver IC.  I couldn't find a listing for the NH00012 anywhere, but I would be willing to bet that it is a similar part.  Several places where I've worked had big shelves of data books, but they all went in the trash when parts data popped up online.  I can't help but wonder if there might be copies hanging around in the basements of libraries of colleges that still teach electrical engineering though.

Actually I have to rescind this answer because I just checked the internet archive’s text copy of the National 1972 MOS IC data book and it says the dual clock driver IC was a MH0009C so this looks like the reference in the EW article was a typo.

Comment: Cool. A *two phase* clock driver. Early processors often needed two clock phases.

Comment: It isn't just the "H" in NH that makes me suspect they're hybrids... it's the size of the package, and knowing that National did indeed implement some hybrid circuits in that same package.  It'd be ironic if I unknowingly had an integrated 2-phase clock driver back then, since I ended up making my own 12-volt 2-phase clock driver out of discretes.